# How to add points to graph in kivy

Tags: python, plot, graph, kivy

I am trying to make a graph with the garden module but have only been able to plot one point.  I am extracting information from a `json` file and trying to make it iterable.  I have looked for hours online for at least one example that shows different plot points other than the given example from the garden docs but I haven't found any. Also after I use a button to add the graph and stays on the screen until exiting. Below is my code.  Please let me know if you have any suggestions!

```
def graph(self, instance): 
        db = TinyDB('entry.json')
        User = Query()
        b = db.search(Query().Date != 0)[:-15:-1]
        f = (int(x['Glucose']) for x in b)
        it = iter(f)
        numbers = next(it)
        graph = Graph(font_size = '35sp', xlabel='Date', ylabel='Blood Sugar (mg/dL)', x_ticks_minor=1, x_ticks_major=1, y_ticks_major=50, y_grid_label=True, x_grid_label=True, padding=5, x_grid=True, y_grid=True, xmin=-0, xmax=14, ymin=50, ymax=400, drawborder = True, size_hint=(.8, .8), pos = (150,150))
        plot = MeshLinePlot(color=[1, 0, 0, 1], bold = True)
        plot.points = [(x, numbers) for x in range(1, 400)]
        graph.add_plot(plot)
        self.add_widget(graph)
```

Comment: with this `[(x, numbers) for x in range(1, 400)]` numbers will be always the same. Try `[(x, next(it)) for x in range(len(f))]`

Comment: @zeeMonkeez It gives the error  `TypeError: object of type 'generator' has no len()`

Comment: @zeeMonkeez I added `length = int(sum(1 for x in numbers))` and used `length` as the range and it worked!